# Understanding TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Example' and 'Example'

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I am working on a project of text simplification using a multi-head attention transformer model. For the same, I am using torchtext for tokenisation and numericalization. The dataset contains two aligned files for training and two aligned files for testing. In the training files, one file contains the complex sentences while the other contains the corresponding simplified sentences.

I read the files as such:

```
training_sentences = open(path + "train.en" , encoding = "utf-8").read().split("\n")
target_sentences = open(path + "train.sen" , encoding = "utf-8").read().split("\n")
```

Next, I tokenised them as such:

```
complicated = spacy.load('en')
simple = spacy.load('en')

def tokenize_complicated(sentence):
   return [tok.text for tok in complicated.tokenizer(sentence)]

def tokenize_simple(sentence):
    return [tok.text for tok in simple.tokenizer(sentence)]

C_TEXT = Field(tokenize=tokenize_complicated, fix_length = 100)
S_TEXT = Field(tokenize=tokenize_simple, fix_length = 100, init_token = "<sos>", eos_token = "<eos>")
```

I then converted into TabularDataset object of torchtext.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'Complicated' : [line for line in training_sentences], 
        'Simple': [line for line in target_sentences]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=["Complicated", "Simple"])

df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
data_fields = [('Complicated', C_TEXT), ('Simple', S_TEXT)]

train = torchtext.data.TabularDataset.splits(path='./', train = "df.csv", format='csv', fields=data_fields, skip_header = True)
```

And then created vocabulary

```
C_TEXT.build_vocab(train)
S_TEXT.build_vocab(train)
```

However, on doing so I got this error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Example' and
>   'Example'

On searching, I came across this solution [here](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/474#issuecomment-454385601) and the error disappeared. However, I am not understanding whether this makes the model take only one instance or it takes all of the dataset?
I would like to know the significance of the index `[0]` so that I can manipulate it effectively for my model.

Answer (score 2):

In the statement:

```
train = torchtext.data.TabularDataset.splits(path='./', train = "df.csv", format='csv', fields=data_fields, skip_header = True)
```

The index `[0]` is used to unpack the dataset which is returned in the customised type of TabularDataset  (a tuple.)
Adding a index at the end of the above statement, we can access the single element inside the tuple.

However in the statement

```
train,val = torchtext.data.TabularDataset.splits(path='./', train = "df.csv", validation = “val.csv”, format='csv', fields=data_fields, skip_header = True)
```

The unpacking is done automatically with first element of tuple in `train` and second in `val`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved the issue passing a `sort_key` and `sort_within_batch` arg to `True` as follows:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 64
train_iterator, valid_iterator, test_iterator = data.BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data, test_data),
    device = device,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    sort_key = lambda x: len(x.src),
    sort_within_batch=True
)
```

Good luck